# How to change date format of datetime data type in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format, alter-table

My date format of `"03-01-2017 10:24:48"` is getting stored in SQL as `"2017-03-01 10:24:48.000"` where my `'dd-mm-yyyy'` format is getting converted to `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format.

How can I change the date format of the column to my desired format? My table already contains data.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The way database stores data is immaterial in this case. Its more about default format for display of dates. If you are using any command line tools like `sqlplus` in case of Oracle or `sqlcmd` in case of MSSQL, there are some parameters at database level which decides default display format for `DATE` and `TIME`. If you are using any GUI tools like TOAD or sqldeveloper, then such tools also have default date & time format in preference section.

Comment: I am using Sql Server Mgmt Studio

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store a date or datetime in any particular string format - they're stored in a **binary format**, and the display is just a setting you can choose.

Comment: thnx Marc for immediate replies but my problem is that I want to store '03' as the dd part of the date, but it is storing it as month(I queried it)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an **8 byte numerical** (binary) value.

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Answer (score 0):

Changing the format does not change the way the data is stored, just the way it is displayed. You can find date and time styles at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: Is there any way to store the date in desired format?