# Wrong Date format stores in SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two columns in SQL Server. I have a SQL bulk insert and it stores date in following format inside the database:

1. The first column type is `DATETIME` - it stores dates in this format: `2018-07-02 00:00:00.000`
2. The second column type is `DATE` and it stores this format: `2018-07-02`

The below part is with out using bulk insert.

When I insert new date its format is changing. I have following code in my C# for first column and second column

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtODR.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
DateTime.ParseExact(txtWorkCompDt.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

When I look in SQL Server, it stores in this way `"2018-02-07 00:00:00.000" and "2018-02-07"`

Why it doesn't store in required format when I try to insert/update from C# (`2018-07-02 00:00:00.000 & 2018-07-02`). What is wrong here? Please help me

SQL Code

```
 DECLARE @P_ORDER_RECIVED_DATE NVARCHAR(100) = '2018/15/02'
 UPDATE [dbo].[T_INSTALATION]
       SET [Order_Recieved_Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@P_ORDER_RECIVED_DATE, 123)   
       where Order_Install_ID = '161'
```

Comment: [Dates are not stored with display format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time/30033028#30033028). The dates in your sample data may be interpeted as `July 2nd 2018` or as `February 7th 2018`. try to check with a date like `15/07/2018`.

Comment: `What is wrong here` Your failure to show the code where you insert/update from C#.

Comment: What is the data type of `Order_Recieved_Date` column?

Comment: datetime is the type

Comment: There is no Year-DAY-Month format support in SQL Server as far as I could tell. To parse 2018/15/02 you have to manually extract the day month etc. portion

Comment: Why are you passing strings around? The .Net DateTime maps directly to SQL Server's DateTime. Just send an instance of DateTime as a parameter to SQL Server and you won't need to worry about string representation formats ever again.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) setting of your SQL Server, if your setting are being set as `yyyy/MM/dd` it will stay that way when you insert or update dates into the db as well, there is nothing wrong with your code.

There is a way of changing that manually using the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) method of SQL Server, it will format the date regardless of the global config.

A sample T-SQL could be:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'en-US');
```

This will return `25-02-2018`

Comment: got an error -> 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: please read the format link attached for better understanding :)

Comment: FORMAT is supported from SQL Server 2012+. If you are using a lower version you could check out the `CONVERT` function.

Answer (score 0):

dd/MM/yyyy can be easily confused with MM/dd/yyyy format.

For example, date 11/02/2018 might represent 11 February or November 2nd.

You are seeing what SSMS is displaying to you. To be on the safe side it is better to store the date in yyyy MM dd format. Regardless of storage format, you should use your own formatting in the `SELECT` statement.

### Update

There is no support for yyyy-dd-MM format. You could manually extract the characters from the given string `2018/15/02` to create date. For future uses, I strongly suggest changing the date format to yyyy-MM-dd or dd/mm/yyyy in the project.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437129/how-to-change-date-format-of-datetime-data-type-in-sql)

Comment: its in yyyy MM dd format but when I try to insert from c# it goes to yyy dd MM

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code of Insert/update?

Comment: Shiblu, DO you mean SQL code ?

Comment: SQL/  C# where your insert code is.

Comment: Updated in OP..